# instantiating an nhibernate Collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

in my Order Entity i am getting a null ref on orderItems. This occurs when an order is first created. I'd like to be able to add something like

```
order.OrderItems = new Iesi.Collections.Set<OrderItem>();
```

the error is "Cannot access protected constructor "Set" here

```
    public class Order
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ISet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddOrderItem(OrderItem item)
        {
            item.Order = this;
            // OrderItems below is null
            OrderItems.Add(item); 
        }

    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="EStore.Domain"
                   namespace="EStore.Domain.Model">

  <class name="Order" table="Orders">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <property name="UserName" column="UserName"/>
    <set name="OrderItems" table="OrderItems" generic="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  inverse="true" >
      <key column="OrderId" not-null="true" />
      <one-to-many class="EStore.Domain.Model.OrderItem, EStore.Domain" />
    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as A Bunch mentioned above.

"Since Iesi.Collections.Set is an abstract class you will need to use one of the implementations such as Iesi.Collections.HashedSet, Iesi.Collections.HybridSet, Iesi.Collections.ListSet or Iesi.Collections.SortedSet"

I've updated the following method. The key part is "new HashedSet(); "

```
 public virtual void AddOrderItem(OrderItem item)
    {
        item.Order = this;
        if (item.Order.OrderItems == null)
        {
            item.Order.OrderItems = new HashedSet<OrderItem>(); 
        }
        OrderItems.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Set OrderItems to a new List in the constructor

```
public Order() {
 OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
}
```

Comment: @frosty: This isn't anything to do with nhibernate.  Without this line you would get this error whether working with NH or not.

Comment: Sorry i should i have mentioned, that Set<OrderItem> is of type Iesi.Collections.Set. However i can't do the following
order.OrderItems = new Iesi.Collections.Set<OrderItem>(); the error is "Cannot access protected constructor "Set" here

Comment: Since Iesi.Collections.Set is an abstract class you will need to use one of the implementations such as Iesi.Collections.HashedSet, Iesi.Collections.HybridSet, Iesi.Collections.ListSet or Iesi.Collections.SortedSet